# Is there Multiple inheritance in Virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++

**If there are two classes directly inherited by virtual inheritance, is only the first class inherited by virtual inheritance? The second is the way of ordinary inheritance?**

`class Student : virtual public Person, virtual public Woman;`

Does code like this exist?

If it exists, is only the first class(Student) inherited by virtual inheritance? The second(Teacher) is the way of ordinary inheritance?

Comment: OK, I've added the code. Is it convenient for you to check?

Comment: I think you have your inheritance grammar backwards.  It should be `class Student : public Person {...}; class Teacher : public Person {...};`  Hence, I think you may need to re-word your question?

Comment: Thank you. You're right. I've corrected it

Comment: Does this code exist? Are both virtual inheritance?

Comment: Yes, this is legal and both classes would be inherited virtually.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance means that a class has more than one direct base class. Full stop.

```
class Student: public Person, public Woman { }; // multiple inheritance -- two direct bases
```

Any base class can be inherited virtually:

```
class Student: public virtual Person { }; // virtual inheritance
```

You can combine multiple inheritance with virtual inheritance if it fits your design:

```
class Student: public virtual Person, public Woman { };

class Student: public Person, public virtual Woman { };

class Student: public virtual Person, public virtual Woman { };
```

`virtual` inheritance says that there should only be one instance of the virtual base regardless of how many times it's used as a base:

```
class base { };
class der1 : public virtual base { }; // one base subobject
class der2 : public virtual base { }; // one base subobject
class top: public der1, public der2 { } ; // one base subobject
```

If it's not virtual, you get multiple sub-objects of the same type:

```
class base { };
class der1 : public base { }; // one base subobject
class der2 : public base { }; // one base subobject
class top : public der1, public der2 { }; // two base subobjects, one each from der1 and der2
```

Comment: I'm sorry, isn't virtual inheritance supposed to be `virtual public`?Or i also can write `public virtual`?

Comment: @yellow-monkey -- try it.